# When using generics, how can I determine if T is negative?

Tags: c#, generics, numeric

I've got a generic class that implements a property called `Value` which is of type `T`. This class is primarily used to handle numbers of different types (decimal, float, etc), but because it is impossible to constrain `T` to numeric types only it could also handle DateTime, string, and anything else you choose to throw at it.

So, in the property setter is there any way I can test if the changed value is negative, in a way that isn't going to fall over or require huge amounts of code or type checking?

The generic class looks a little like this:

```
public class ValueText<T> 
{
    private T _value;
    private bool _isNeg;

    public bool IsNegative { get { return _isNeg; } }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            //check if the new value is the same as the old value:
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, _value))
                return;

            _value = value;

            _isNeg = ...what?...;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this in one line with no type checking. There is one caveat though - this method will not play nice if the concrete type doesn't implement `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>`. If you don't implement one of those interfaces then you will get a System.ArgumentException, but this is easily accommodated (especially as it is most likely to occur for one of your own custom types, I don't think there are many BCL types that don't implement it).

All you need is this nifty line of code:

```
bool isNegative = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, default(T)) < 0;
```

The real beauty in this one is the `default(T)` - this is what accommodates strings, DateTimes, etc. The concrete type will get compared to the default value of the type, and for the likes of string or DateTime the `Compare()` will never return less than zero when comparing to the default.

Check out this sample, which includes an example custom struct so you can see the `IComparable` in action:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Comparing different value (and reference) types to zero:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking int '9' : {0}", IsNegative(9));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking int '-9': {0}", IsNegative(-9));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking int '0' : {0}", IsNegative(0));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking decimal '9' : {0}", IsNegative(9m));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking decimal '-9': {0}", IsNegative(-9m));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking decimal '0' : {0}", IsNegative(0m));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking float '9'  : {0}", IsNegative(9f));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking float '-9' : {0}", IsNegative(-9f));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking float '0'  : {0}", IsNegative(0f));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking long '9'  : {0}", IsNegative(9L));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking long '-9' : {0}", IsNegative(-9L));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking long '0'  : {0}", IsNegative(0L));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking string '9'   : {0}", IsNegative("9"));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking string '-9'  : {0}", IsNegative("-9"));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking string empty : {0}", IsNegative(string.Empty));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking string null  : {0}", IsNegative((string)null));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking DateTime.Now '{0}' : {1}", DateTime.Now, IsNegative(DateTime.Now));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking DateTime.Max '{0}' : {1}", DateTime.MaxValue, IsNegative(DateTime.MaxValue));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking DateTime.Min '{0}' : {1}", DateTime.MinValue, IsNegative(DateTime.MinValue));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking positive MyStruct : {0}", IsNegative(new MyStruct() { MainValue = 9 }));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking negative MyStruct : {0}", IsNegative(new MyStruct() { MainValue = -9 }));
        Console.WriteLine("Checking zero MyStruct     : {0}", IsNegative(new MyStruct() { MainValue = 0 }));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool IsNegative<T>(T value)
    {
        return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, default(T)) < 0;
    }

    private struct MyStruct : IComparable<MyStruct>, IComparer<MyStruct>
    {
        public int MainValue;

        public int CompareTo(MyStruct other)
        {
            return MainValue - other.MainValue;
        }

        public int Compare(MyStruct x, MyStruct y)
        {
            return x.MainValue - y.MainValue;
        }
    }
}
```